# Idris - lazy evaluation issue

Tags: monads, lazy-evaluation, idris

Consider this program:

```
module test

import Effects
import Effect.StdIO

(>>==) : Maybe a -> Lazy (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
(>>==) Nothing (Delay map) = Nothing
(>>==) (Just x) (Delay map) = map x

nothing : String -> Eff (Maybe String) [STDIO]
nothing s = do
    putStrLn s
    pure Nothing

func : Maybe String -> String -> Maybe String
func Nothing _ = Nothing
func (Just s) t = Just (s ++ t)

test : Eff () [STDIO]
test = do
    let m = !(nothing "a") >>== (func !(nothing "b"))
    putStrLn "end"

main : IO ()
main = run test
```

since the right hand side of `>>==` is declared lazy and `!(nothing "a")` returns `Nothing`, I would expect that the right hand side of `>>==` would not be evaluated.

But actually it does get evaluated, and I can't understand why...

More broadly, I'm trying to concatenate `Eff` computations that return maybe and stop the execution when I get the first `Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

Desugar the ! notation.

```
test = do
    x <- nothing "a"
    y <- nothing "b"
    let m = x >>== (func y)
    putStrLn "end"
```

Clearly "a", "b", and "end" will all be printed, but `func` may not be evaluated.

I think you'll need have to define `>>==` to act on (some) `Eff` values, rather than directly on `Maybe`s.

HTH

Comment: What I actually would like is that the computation stops after `nothing "a"`, so that `"b"` is never printed. I guess this does not happen because the `do` notation is working in the wrong context, i.e. `Eff` instead of `Maybe`. In Haskell I would tackle this using the `MaybeT` monad transformer, is there something similiar in Idris? Does dependent types allow me to do something cleaner?

Comment: Add the `EXCEPTION ()` effect.  Have `nothing` call `raise ()`, there's already a handler based on Maybe defined that works no matter what you raise.